# Регулярное выражение для проверки пароля

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста правильно написать регулярное выражение для пароля. Строка должна быть не меньше 8 символов, содержать как минимум 1 большую букву, одну маленькую букву и ЛИБО спец. символ ЛИБО цифру.

Сейчас у меня есть модель, но здесь идет И спец. символ И цифра должна быть, как сделать проверку именно Либо спец. символ либо цифра?

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,40})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше выражение почти готово: только `\d` надо перенести в `[@#$%]` и удалить ограничение в 40 символов:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9@#$%]).{8,}$
                            ^^^^
```

Если этот шаблон используется в `String#matches`, `^` и `$` можно удалить. Если верхнее ограничение в 40 символов нужно (не указано в вопросе), можно вернуть `{8,40}`.

Суть в том, что отношения между членами внутри символьного класса отношения ИЛИ, поэтому блок `(?=.*[0-9@#$%])` требует присутствия в строке ИЛИ цифр, или указанных символов.

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/eN8cJ5/1)

[Пример на Java](http://ideone.com/8jD5xv):

```
String s = "###abcA@@";
String pat = "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9@#$%]).{8,}";
if (s.matches(pat)) {
    System.out.println("Пароль действителен"); 
}
else {
    System.out.println("Пароль недействителен"); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!